# How do I recurrsively call multiple URLs using Puppeteer and Headless Chrome?

Tags: puppeteer, headless, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to write a program to scan multiple URLs at the same time (parallelizaiton) and I have extracted sitemap and stored it as an array in a Variable as shown below. But i am unable to open using Puppeteer. I am getting the below error:

originalMessage: 'Cannot navigate to invalid URL'

My code below. Can someone please help me out .

```
const sitemapper = require('@mastixmc/sitemapper');
const SitemapXMLParser = require('sitemap-xml-parser');
const url = 'https://edition.cnn.com/sitemaps/sitemap-section.xml';

/*If sitemapindex (link of xml or gz file) is written in sitemap, the URL will be accessed.
You can optionally specify the number of concurrent accesses and the number of milliseconds after processing and access to resume processing after a delay.
*/

const options = {
    delay: 3000,
    limit: 50000
};

const sitemapXMLParser = new SitemapXMLParser(url, options);

sitemapXMLParser.fetch().then(result => {
    var locs = result.map(value => value.loc)   
    var locsFiltered = locs.toString().replace("[",'<br>');
    const urls = locsFiltered
    console.log(locsFiltered)
   

const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function scrapeProduct(url) {
    const urls = locsFiltered
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });
    for (i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        const url = urls[i];
        const promise = page.waitForNavigation({
            waitUntil: "networkidle2"
        });
        await page.goto(`${url}`);
    }};
   
    scrapeProduct();
    
});
```

Comment: Invalid url means what it sounds like. It's probably a relative url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see invalid URL because you've convert an array into URL string by wrong method.
These line is a better one:

```
// var locsFiltered = locs.toString().replace("[",'<br>') // This is wrong
// const urls = locsFiltered                              // So value is invalid
// console.log(locsFiltered)

const urls = locs.map(value => value[0])  // This is better
```

So to scrape CNN sites, i've added `puppeteer-cluster` for speed:

```
const { Cluster } = require('puppeteer-cluster')
const sitemapper = require('@mastixmc/sitemapper')
const SitemapXMLParser = require('sitemap-xml-parser')
const url = 'https://edition.cnn.com/sitemaps/sitemap-section.xml'


async function scrapeProduct(locs) {
    const urls = locs.map(value => value[0])
    const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
        concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_CONTEXT,
        maxConcurrency: 2, // You can set this to any number you like
        puppeteerOptions: {
            headless: false,
            devtools: false,
            args: [],
        }
    })

    await cluster.task(async ({ page, data: url }) => {
        await page.goto(url, {timeout: 0, waitUntil: 'networkidle2'})
        const screen = await page.screenshot()
        // Store screenshot, do something else
    })

    for (i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        console.log(urls[i])
        await cluster.queue(urls[i])
    }

    await cluster.idle()
    await cluster.close()
}

/******
If sitemapindex (link of xml or gz file) is written in sitemap, the URL will be accessed.
You can optionally specify the number of concurrent accesses and the number of milliseconds after processing and access to resume processing after a delay.
*******/
const options = {
    delay: 3000,
    limit: 50000
}
const sitemapXMLParser = new SitemapXMLParser(url, options)
sitemapXMLParser.fetch().then(async result => {
    var locs = result.map(value => value.loc)
    await scrapeProduct(locs)
})
```

Comment: Thank You! this work liked a magic! Ton of thanks

Comment: Nice. my pleasure